# PHP socket_read exits while loop directly to a finally clause

Tags: php, sockets, while-loop

I am a new php programmer that has extensive experience in C# .NET.  I am attempting to read a UDP datagram that is broadcast every two seconds on the network using php so that it can be displayed on a web page. I've done similar things in the past on the .NET environment.
The issue I am having is that there is a while loop that reads the UDP datagram.  The first time it does a read it is successful.  However the loop never continues.  The code falls through to the finally clause and terminates.  It never reaches the catch statement either.  Here is the code:

```
            //Create a UDP socket
            if(!($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP)))
            {
                 $errorcode = socket_last_error();
                 $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
                 die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
            }

            echo "Socket created fine  <br>";

            // Bind the source address
            if( !socket_bind($socket, "192.168.1.33" , 50008) ){
                 $errorcode = socket_last_error();
                 echo "BIND failed <br>";
                 $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
                 die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
            }
            echo "Socket bind OK <br>";

            socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec">
            socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array("sec">
            if (!socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) {
                   echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
               }

            socket_set_block($socket);
            $loop_counter = 0;
            try {
              while(1){
                   usleep(1.0 * 1000000); 
                   echo socket_read($socket,1024, PHP_BINARY_READ );
                   echo "<br>";
                   flush_buffers();

                   }
                 }

             catch(Exception $e) {
                  echo "Exception";
                  echo $e->getMessage();
             }

             finally {
            echo "last socket error =  ";
            echo  socket_last_error($socket);
            echo "<br>";
             echo "Executed the finally clause <Br>";
             socket_close($socket);
            }
```

The output of this code is
Socket created fine
Socket bind OK
24.630000000000052:24.370000000000005:22.3:36.7:False
last socket error = 0
Executed the finally clause

I have tried many things, but have not come up with a solution. The web server is Apache, and the platform is the raspberry pi.
Thanks for any help, Tom

Comment: So you have a web server running with a PHP script, and that script then listens indefinitely on a socket? Apache (and most web servers) aren’t really built for long-running connections, and PHP, when in a web context, isn’t either. You might be running into a timeout from either. I’d move your socket code to a PHP CLI and use long-polling from the web script. The latter could start/stop the CLI, maybe, but I’d keep them separated.

Comment: Thanks for this info.  I have never programmed for a web page or php before. I decided to use php since a google search suggested this approach.  However, I am open to any other approach that may be good.  Ajax, what ever.  All this is new to me at this point. I just want it as simple as possible.  The web page will just display 5 pieces of info every two or so seconds.

Comment: PHP on the CLI is really easy. You can just invoke it using `php file.php`. You can use supervisord to keep it running continuously. Have it write to something more stable. If history isn’t need, just write to the same file. If it is, SQLite is a great file-based database.

Comment: Ok, I am now using a file instead of the UDP stream. I am using the fetch command in the web server.  I can load the file from the web server root if I put it in manually.  However I then try fetch('file:///home/pi/Programming/data.csv' )  However it never finds the file.  I told you I am new to this!  The permissions give read to everyone.